# Access anonymous functions in the console

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

If my javascript is already running, and I have a function like this in the code:

```
var myObject= {
    foo: function() {
    }
};
```

I can log calls to the function and get an alert in the console when it's called  by submitting this:

```
myObject.foo = function(c) {alert('Called!');}
```

How can I do the same if the javascript method is set up as follows:

```
! function(a) {
    a.SOMEOBJ= function() {
        this.varA= {}, this.varB = {}
    };
    var b = a.SOMEOBJ.prototype;
    b.bar= function() {
        return 1
    }, b.foo= function(b) {
       //Do some calc
       //I want to add an alert here. . .
    }
}(ANOTHEROBJ);
```

What's this type of method called and how can I add a line to it so that I get an alert in the Developer tools console when it's called?

Comment: It's a "self executing anonymous function", that's how It's called ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what you are trying, perhaps this might help you:

```
var x={};

(function(a) {
  // alert(a.ich);
    a.SOMEOBJ =  {
        varA: {}, varB : {}
    };
    var b = a.SOMEOBJ;

    b.bar= function() {
        return 1;
    };

    b.foo= function(b) {
       alert(b);
    };

})(x);

x.SOMEOBJ.foo("hi");
```